# Does is_numeric() obviate the need for mysql_real_escape_string() for numeric data? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security, escaping

I have a function that takes MySQL table ids as input.

Rather than apply mysql_real_escape_string, can I just use is_numeric?

Like so:

```
protected function validId($id) {
    if(!is_numeric($id)) return false; 
    // else do stuff
}
```

Edit:

I also wanted to mention that I sometimes have used this:

$val = (int)$val;

Here is the section on type casting from the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

Also, I believe that mysql_real_escape_string requires a hit to the database for each use. Why do that when validating integers?

Edit2:

Also, is_int() will not work with form input, which is why I'm using is_numeric. But perhaps doing something like this would solve the problem and work faster/create less server load:

```
protected function validId($id) {
    if(!is_numeric($id)) return false;  // confirm it is number or numeric string
    $id = (int) $id; // cast to int (will chop off decimals I believe)
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, I would recommend staying away from the mysql_* function library, as it is deprecated. Use the MySQLi extension, or, better yet, the PDO library.

Comment: @spryno724 Yes, I know. Need to finish what I started though, then go back and replace everything with PDO afterwards.

Comment: I can relate. |-( I've got projects of my own like that. Just though you might like to know.

Comment: Don't use deprecated functions to finish what you've started. When you write new code, use PDO or MySQLi instead. That gives you less code to rewrite when the project is finished, and helps you learn the newer methodology sooner rather than later. There isn't really a convincing reason to write new code with deprecated functions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

`is_numeric` allows hexadecimal notation. If you have it wrapped in quotes in your query then it will just result in `0`, but if you don't then it will be interpreted correctly. `is_numeric` also allows scientific notation, which suffers the same problems.

Personally, I'd suggest `intval()`, but `mysql_real_escape_string` is safer.

If it's the length of the function name, just do this and forget about it:

```
function esc($str) {return mysql_real_escape_string($str);}
```

Comment: See my edit: I also wonder about using (int) to cast values as integer.

Comment: That is essentailly the same as `intval`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how mysql_real_escape_string is safer than inval()/(int) though. How can an integer be unsafe? There is nothing to escape? I doubt PHP would have a bug that would affect something so fundamental as type casting that would allow SQL injection through int values.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: Why *not* call the escape function though? It's not hurting anything (perf wise it's a hell of a lot faster than *parsing* the PHP script it's running with...)

Comment: @BillyONeal Why not? because mysql_real_escape_string() makes a db hit every time it's called. PHP has to ask MySQL how to escape each string. There is no parsing in PHP when casting as int. Only ints are expected and ints are safe. (This would not be a problem if PHP was not a loosely typed language) I'm still not convinced I should use mysql_real_escape_string() in this situation. It still seems like a waste.

Comment: Personally I just use `addslashes`. It doesn't escape newlines or DEL, but that's never given me any problems.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does not cause any database communication and is definitely the right thing to do for manual escaping. `addslashes` will fail for some East Asian multibyte encodings and when the database is using ANSI SQL quotes.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string ONLY WORKS if you have an active db connection. That is a clue that yes, it does make a request to the server. Not sure if it's on every invocation mysql_real_escape_string, but it might be.